# Cant pass hibernate transaction to actually fill tables. Tables are empty

Tags: java, database, postgresql, hibernate

im trying to learn hibernate and this is my first try. I made 3 entity properties and want to create schema for them and then store objects into DB all using hibernate. But when i try to execute session.save schema is generating but tables are not filling with data.

```
@Entity
public class Address {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String streetName;

    public Address() {
    }

    public Address(String streetName) {
        this.setId(-1);
        this.streetName = streetName;
    }

    //some setters/getters
}
```

ItMan.class

```
@Entity
public class ItMan implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private int brainpower;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    Address address;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    Phone phone;

    public ItMan() {
    }

    public ItMan(String name, int brainpower, Address address, Phone phone) {
        this.setId(-1);
        this.name = name;
        this.brainpower = brainpower;
        this.address = address;
        this.phone = phone;
    }

   //some setters/getters
}
```

Phone.class

```
@Entity
public class Phone implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String number;

    public Phone() {
    }

    public Phone(String number) {
        this.setId(-1);
        this.number = number;
    }

    //some setters/getters
}
```

DBService

```
public class HibernateDBServiceImpl implements DBService {

    private final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public HibernateDBServiceImpl() {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Address.class);
        configuration.addAnnotatedClass(ItMan.class);
        configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Phone.class);
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "org.postgresql.Driver");
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:postgresql:myDB");
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", "postgres");
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.useSSL", "false");
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans", "true");

        sessionFactory = createSessionFactory(configuration);
    }

    private static SessionFactory createSessionFactory(Configuration configuration) {
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();
        builder.applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = builder.build();
        return configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    }

@Override
public void save(Object object) {
    /*try (Session session = sessionFactory.openSession()) {
        session.save(object);
    }*/
    runInSession(session -> {
        session.save(object);
        return true;
    });
}

@Override
public Object read(Class clazz, String condition) {
    long a = Long.getLong(condition);
    return runInSession(session -> {
        return session.load(clazz, a);
    });
}
```

How can i tweak my code so it actual saves data to DB?

Comment: Add transaction manager.

Comment: private <R> R runInSession(Function<Session, R> function) {
        try (Session session = sessionFactory.openSession()) {
            Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            R result = function.apply(session);
            transaction.commit();
            return result;
        }
    }

Comment: https://github.com/brunobannan1/learning    - here's my github, for all code.

Comment: Nope, no JPA API to be seen here. That is Hibernate API. Kindly tag correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem with removing configuration property:

```
configuration.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
```

Dont know what exactly is going on, maybe someone in comments can explain this: Why if i removing this - i made hibernate to keep save data in DB and if i keep this configuration and dont even start program again (which will purge all of schemes cos of this config property) i got no data in DB.

Answer (score 0):

```
configuration.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
```

This will create schema from scratch, every time you run your code. You should change "create" to "update" or "none"

here is the docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html

Comment: yes i know it, but the problem is that im checking DB right after run code, without start of next code run. Somehow data is wiped still.